# PDFLatex Kile under Linux readable - Windows not

Tags: pdf, pdflatex

I am having a strange problem:
If I compile a PDF with Texlive 2013, Kile under Ubuntu 14.04 everything is OK with the PDF and I can open it. If I try to open the same PDF under Windows it does not work, random pages are missing, eg....!

My workaround is to open the pdf under ubuntu and print it again as a new pdf file and everything can be read by Windows.

Where is the problem? Am I missing a Windows compatibility by any Kile option? Is there some specific line to change in the pdf header file?

This is my system:

> Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS Qt: 4.8.6 KDE Development Platform: 4.13.3 Kile:
>   2.1.3
>
> Windows 7 & Windows 8 - Acorbat Reader 11

Comment: It looks like the PDF has errors that the Ubuntu viewer is more forgiveful but without the looking at the PDF it's only a guess.

Comment: ok thanks, that was the problem, i reduced compiling errors too 0 and now it is working.
Would be interesting why PDF Viewers under Linux are more friendly to see files with small errors